# Size of exported folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

What is the difference between the project folder in android studio directory which is in my case nearly 50 megabytes and the .zip file which i export from inside the android studio which is nearly 2 megabytes only ?

and if i send a friend both folders , what is the difference he will face ?

Comment: You really shouldn't zip an Android Studio project to share it. The .idea folder will contain unremoved  config files that you manually have to remove. Use Git instead. You'll have to configure the .gitignore, but at least you don't need to deal with the minefield of system-specific config and build files

Answer (score 0):

`.zip` is an archive file format that supports lossless data compression, i.e. your `.zip` file is your compressed project folder. Assuming that's what you created the `.zip` file from and not something else.

If you send your friend your project folder and the `.zip` file, the only difference should be in the download times. Once again assuming your `.zip` file was created from your project folder, and that your friend has software that can open a `.zip` archive. Which they should have, since it's free and easily downloadable or comes with their operating system.